# CSS trick-- nested span tags where the child needs to below the parent

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have a tricky CSS situation here. 
Basically I have nested span tags that looks like this:

```
<span>A
  <span>test</span>
</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>C</span>
```

I need "test" to be below "A" with all three letters (A, B, C) being equal width.

The ideal result would look like this:

```
ABC
test
```

What I'm getting now is this:

```
A   BC
test
```

Is this possible? I played with `float` property, but it didn't work because there could be other text before the letter in question:

```
SOME OTHER TEXT. ABC
                 test
```

I set up a fiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/grnbeagle/g3hG8/), and the goal is to reduce the width of highlighted "A". So far I have `position:relative` and `top`/`left` adjustment.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this updated fiddle for a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/g3hG8/4/

Setting the wrapping `span`s `position: relative;` and then the child `span`s `position: absolute;` achieves the effect you desire.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `position: absolute;`

[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/sBK4G/)

N.B. in order to get the letters to display tightly (as if the markup was `<span>ABC</span>`) you need to remove *all* white space from between the tags, as my fiddle does.

```
<span>H</span><span>i</span><span> </span>
<span style="background:yellow; position: relative;">A<span style="font-size:0.8em; font-weight:bold; position:absolute; top:10px; left: 0;">test</span>
</span><span>B</span><span>C</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @MattBall. Nathan was a tad quicker.

Comment: @Grnbeagle: you're right, he was! Almost exactly the same answer, too.