# Python regex: remove certain HTML tags and the contents in them

Tags: python, html, regex, tags

If I have a string that contains this:

```
<p><span class=love><p>miracle</p>...</span></p><br>love</br>
```

And I want to remove the string:

```
<span class=love><p>miracle</p>...</span>
```

and maybe some other HTML tags. At the same time, the other tags and the contents in them will be reserved.

The result should be like this:

```
<p></p><br>love</br>
```

I want to know how to do this using regex pattern?
what I have tried :

```
r=re.compile(r'<span class=love>.*?(?=</span>)')
r.sub('',s)
```

but it will leave the

```
</span>
```

can you help me using re module this time?and i will learn html parser next

Comment: `and maybe some other HTML tags..` - If you are going to remove lots of different things, you should look into parsing the HTML rather than using Regex.

Comment: there's no way you can do this in regex...usean html parser

Comment: @Anirudh - incorrect, as poke's answer demonstrated, a regex can select two strings and anything in between

Comment: @Anirudh Completely false, as underlined by  Chris Stratton. People are so obsessed by the catechetical assertion that 'regexes can't parse HTML documents' that they write whatsoever as soon as they see a bit of regex on an HTML text.

Comment: @ChrisStratton 1>the regex in answer won't work if there are nested span tags..2>many times a span tag don't have an ending tag hence breaking the code..there are n no of other cases for that regex to fail..if you want i can list 10 other cases where the regex would break

Comment: @eyquem with 2 reasons above here are other cases where the regex would break: 3>a class name can be within `"`,`'`.the regex below wont work for them.. 4>a span tag can have other attributes to which the regex doesn't address 5>a span tag can have n number of spaces between attributes to which the regex doesn't address

Comment: @Anirudh - a regex may not be able to handle everything which as actual HTML parser can, but contrary to your original claim it can "do this" where "this" is the problem of the question asked.

Comment: @ChrisStratton unless **you** are the one who created the html,there's no way you could infer the grammer of html through regex

Comment: @Anirudh Thank you for your comment. You seem to know HTML far better than me.  I know all these critics against regexes used for HTML. I didn't mean that these drawbacks don't exist, I meant that your saying  that a regex couldn't do what the OP asked is false in the precise case of the OP's string. As you expressed, he could think that it's absolutely impossible to analyze a text as soon as it has tags in it, and that is completely false. - That said, you are right that he may be unaware of the dangers to perform such an analyze if its string happens to be a more complex HTML text.

Comment: @Anirudh I hadn't seen the last comment of Chris before posting mine. He says exactly the same as me

Comment: @Anirudh Infering the grammar or extracting the tree of an HTML text isn't what is aimed at by the OP: this is parsing in the pure sense (as far as I correctly understood the pure sense of parsing in programming) of the word 'parse'. I agree that regexes can't extract the tree of a tagged text (HTML, XML etc), they can't parse them. But they can analyze them.

Comment: @Anirudh By the way, since you know well HTML, could you say me if there can be nested **<span...>.....</span>** inside already nested span tags , please. That is to say, is the nesting of <span> tags limited to one level, or may the level of nesting span tags be anything ? For the following pattern catches **<span class=love>....</span>** whatever is between the tag start and the tag end, if and only if there are only one level of <span> tags inside it: ``'<span class=love>(?:.*?(?=<span[^>]*>)(?:<span[^>]*>.*?</span>)?)*.*?</span>'``. This is to answer for your point 1/

Comment: @eyquem [nested span tags are valid even in xhtml..forget about html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078127/are-nested-span-tags-ok-in-xhtml)

Comment: @eyquem [with n number of level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086372/css-trick-nested-span-tags-where-the-child-needs-to-below-the-parent)

Comment: @Anirudh OK, thank you very much. So it's the responsability of the OP to know what he does: either he uses a regex that can do the limited task he wants because he knows or he takes the risk that the HTML has no nested span tags; either he is obliged to use an adapted parser to perform substitutions on more complicated HTML text.

Comment: @Anirudh what you have debated is very meaningful to me.I know the boundedness of the pure regex as the question mentiond,but it do can resolve my problem in this particular situation. For other,it may need the HtmlParser Module.Thanks for you idea

Comment: @eyquem The discuss you give is wonderful.Last night,I read the python book,it mention that the htmlparser module does not identification all the html tags,is that the truth? If so,the pure can help deal with those tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First things first: [Don’t parse HTML using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

That being said, if there is no additional span tag within that span tag, then you could do it like this:

```
text = re.sub('<span class=love>.*?</span>', '', text)
```

On a side note: paragraph tags are not supposed to go within span tags (only [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) is).

---

The expression you have tried, `<span class=love>.*?(?=</span>)`, is already quite good. The problem is that the lookahead `(?=</span>)` will never match what it looks ahead for. So the expression will stop immediately *before* the closing span tag. You now could manually add a closing span at the end, i.e. `<span class=love>.*?(?=</span>)</span>`, but that’s not really necessary: The `.*?` is a non-greedy expression. It will try to match as little as possible. So in `.*?</span>` the `.*?` will only match until a closing span is found where it immediately stops.

Comment: your answer is helpful to me!It is better than mine! This is the first time to post question is StackOverFlow,I am exited for the timely attention and solve!Thanks!

Comment: @poke He doesn't want to parse an HTML document, he just want to substitute some parts of it.

Comment: @eyquem I’m fully aware of that. It’s just a disclaimer, that I know that topic, which I add to any answers like these, to prevent people from arguing about the HTML & regexp topic… :/

Comment: OK , thank you , it's a good precaution. But I don't like the linked post, it explains nearly nothing on the why regexes can't parse XML docs